# How to replace and append a component's view in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-components

So I infiltrate some HTML code into my app using this code:

```
fetchDashboard() {
    const requestOptions: Object = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders().append('Authorization', 'Bearer <tokenhere>'),
      responseType: 'text'
    }
    this.http.get<string>('http://localhost:3000/avior/dashboard',
        requestOptions)
            .subscribe(response => {
                   // replace me with modification of component view
                   console.log(response);
            }
    );
}
```

I execute this code in my view with `<a class="dropdown-item" (click)=fetchDashboard()>Dashboard</a>`

For the optimal solution:

- How can I replace and append to a certain component's view (since the view consists of multiple components)?

Optional question:

- Is there a way to append directly to DOM? Since Angular doesn't
  properly use the DOM that doesn't sound like a viable solution to me and hence is optional.

Comment: I found this https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: sounds like an ngIf if else template kind of situation

Comment: You could simply set the [innerHTML] value of a div which you reference via its id. something like <div #hereMyTag> and in .ts: hereMyTag.innerHtml = "your inserted HTML"

Comment: I managed to get Renderer2 implemented, but it prints out my HTML as a string, so it's not fitting -_-

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

.ts

```
.subscribe(response => {
     this.aComponentData = response;
}
```

view.html:

```
<a-component [data]="aComponentData"></a-component>

<b-component></b-component>
```

a.component.ts

```
@Input() data: string;
```

a.component.html

```
<div [innerHtml]="data"></div>
```

Comment: Doesn't appear to work, I do not use routing though, maybe that's the mistake? Please check the updated question.

Comment: You want to replace whole html it just some variables

Comment: I forgot to add to view.html. Now I get `'app-dashboard' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-dashboard' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-dashboard' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.`, `Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'app-dashboard'.
1. If 'app-dashboard' is an Angular component and it has 'data' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-dashboard' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS..`

Comment: Is dashboard component is added in the same module?

Comment: I just added it in app.component.html and it gives me these errors

Comment: You have to create a component Dashboard, you can't just add ab\anything in the html. Only the selector of the created components work

Comment: The StackBlitz appears to miss CSS, and I don't find any CSS in my files and only Bootstrap in the angular.json

Answer (score 0):

`ng-template` is the proper tool for conditionally displaying "complex content".

Instead of writing down a long winded answer, I will just provide the link to a blog post at Angular University: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/
Because I'm on mobile.

It compares `ng-template` `ng-container` and more.

There are more blogs dealing with those topics than this mentioned blog. It was the first result when googling for ng-template.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer without a provided fitting example

Comment: Just as you usually would `(click)="functionName($event)"`